# Autoencoder not able to generate same input and output value

Tags: neural-networks, python, autoencoders, theano

I am doing some work with Theano based auto-encoder, giving input as samples from mixture of Gaussians, one hidden layer. I expected output to be same as input, but I am not achieving it. I have been inspired by [this](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/dA.html) tutorial for implemenation. Is autoencoder with only one hidden layer is also sufficient to recover exact replica of output ?

My code looks like below :

```
` def train(self, n_epochs=100, mini_batch_size=1, learning_rate=0.01):
    index = T.lscalar()
    x=T.matrix('x')
    params = [self.W, self.b1, self.b2]
    hidden = self.activation_function(T.dot(x, self.W)+self.b1)
    output = T.dot(hidden,T.transpose(self.W))+self.b2
    output = self.output_function(output)


    # Use mean square error
    L = T.sum((x - output) ** 2)
    cost = L.mean()

    updates=[]

    #Return gradient with respect to W, b1, b2.
    gparams = T.grad(cost,params)

    #Create a list of 2 tuples for updates.
    for param, gparam in zip(params, gparams):
        updates.append((param, param-learning_rate*gparam))

    #Train given a mini-batch of the data.
    train = th.function(inputs=[index], outputs=cost, updates=updates,
                        givens={x:self.X[index:index+mini_batch_size,:]})
    import time
    start_time = time.clock()
    acc_cost = []
    for epoch in xrange(n_epochs):

        #print "Epoch:", epoch
        for row in xrange(0,self.m, mini_batch_size):
            cost = train(row)
        acc_cost.append(cost)

    plt.plot(range(n_epochs), acc_cost)
    plt.ylabel("cost")
    plt.xlabel("epochs")
    plt.show()

    # Format input data for plotable format
    norm_data = self.X.get_value()
    plot_var1 = []
    plot_var1.append(norm_data[:,0])
    plot_var2 = []
    plot_var2.append(norm_data[:,1])
    plt.plot(plot_var1, plot_var2, 'ro')

    # Hidden output
    x=T.dmatrix('x')
    hidden = self.activation_function(T.dot(x,self.W)+self.b1)
    transformed_data = th.function(inputs=[x], outputs=[hidden])
    hidden_data = transformed_data(self.X.get_value())
    #print "hidden_output ", hidden_data[0]

    # final output
    y=T.dmatrix('y')
    W = T.transpose(self.W)
    output = self.activation_function(T.dot(y,W) + self.b2)
    transformed_data = th.function(inputs=[y], outputs=[output])
    output_data = transformed_data(hidden_data[0])[0]
    print "decoded_output ", output_data

    # Format output data for plotable format
    plot_var1 = []
    plot_var1.append(output_data[:,0])
    plot_var2 = []
    plot_var2.append(output_data[:,1])
    plt.plot(plot_var1, plot_var2, 'bo')
    plt.show()



'
```

My learning curve looks like [image: neural network learning curve] and my plot for input(red colour) and output value(blue) colour[image: input and output data for neural network]. 
My concept that I should expect same input/output is wrong or what ?